# Display author's name and avatar in post's sidebar

Tags: posts, author

I'd like to display the post author's name and avatar on posts sidebar but I can't find any info on it.

Is there a shortcode or piece of code to do this ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Write your own widget :-)

Comment: Well I'd love to, but I have no idea how to do this ;) 
Any function I should use ?

Comment: Use `get_queried_object()->post_author` in single page view in the widget to get the post author ID and then take it from there

Answer (score 2):

Display author's avatar and name in single page sidebar. Add this code in sidebar.php or single.php

```
if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
    echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), 75 );
    echo get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' );
}
```

Here 75 number is the avatar size.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using it in [Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) then :

You can display author name by using

```
<?php $author = get_the_author();
   echo $author; ?>
```

and you can display post author avatar using

```
<?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 32 ); ?>
```

you can change 32 size to whatever your need.

Hope this will work for you.

thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I add this to the sidebar from the loop ?

Comment: yes you can add this for single post also. but for single post, you have to put the post id to get author id and name or avatar.

Answer (score 0):

Display author's name and avatar in Post page and single post page sidebar.
Put this code in sidebar.php

```
        if(is_home() || is_single()){
           echo get_avatar( $post->post_author,'100');
           echo get_the_author($post->post_author);
        }
```

I hope useful.